# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@angular/core/src/util" IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have this ionic application which was working fine till yesterday. but today when i tried to run , its not running.
Its throwing an error saying `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@angular/core/src/util"`. I have no idea what could be the cause. I tried to search on google with the error but no luck.

I thought this could be because my anguler files are disappeared somehow. so i tried to run `npm install`  still no luck
Can anyone please help me to find out what could be the cause of this error.??

The error says

[image]

Comment: Are the resources of `“@angular/core/src/util”` available in your project?

Comment: yes, i can see there are folder inside  `@angular/core/src/util `

Only two files there inside util . one is  `decorator.d.ts ` and one is  `lang.d.ts `

Comment: Depending on version Remove '/src/util' from your ts import.

Comment: oh okay thanks kyler that helped :)

Comment: which module you are importing ?