# How to solve Error: Cannot find module "@angular/core/src/view/util”

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

I am building an ionic project for my final year project, and suddenly my laptop got a short circuit. So right now I'm developing back my project through multiple computers/laptop, but my project seems cannot shows it output. Every time I did `ionic serve`, it is throwing an error saying `Runtime Error: Cannot find module "@angular/core/src/view/util"`. I've already google about this but there is no answer until now even there is one similar question with me, it still cannot solve this problem. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Did you try ```npm install``` at the project path in terminal??

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852812/uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-angular-core-src-util-ionic-3 Did you try what this one did? `npm install` and `remove '/src/util' from your ts import`

Comment: @DanielPiñeiro I already did `npm install` but did not do the remove `/src/util` from ts import as I didn't understand which one of the ts part.

Comment: Check in your project where `/src/util` is declared and if you are really using it.

Answer (score 2):

Search in the project `@angular/core/src/view/util` and substitute it with `@angular/core`. This is probably a problem caused by the auto-importer, since it randomly imports the symbol by a point where it's exported. But you should never and never again import something from a `src` folder!

Comment: I change `import { resolveDefinition } from '@angular/core/src/view/util';` to `import { resolveDefinition } from '@angular/core';`.. but it appears as error

Comment: wait.. I found the problem.. it because I used `resolveDefinition(err)` instead of `resolve(err)`..Anyway, thank you for all the suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

delete the node-module folder.
run 'npm install' command from the root directory.
this should do the trick.
this installs every dependency listed in your package.json file.
if u want to install new packages,just run 'npm i *your package name*